# How do I change this Spring Test Framework Test to work with a JSON return?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-test-mvc

I am trying to change the following Spring Test Framework to test for a the following json return:

```
{"user":"John ","name":"JohnSmith"}
```

Here is my test code and I just dont know how to change it to check for JSON and the value in JSON. It will be great if someone can tell me what to change.. thanks

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {WebMVCConfig.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class TestHelloWorldWeb
{
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup()
    {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void getFoo() throws Exception
    {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/ask")
                .accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(view().name("helloworld"))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.model().attribute("user", "JohnSmith"))
        ;


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.user").value("john"));
```

with dependency :

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
<artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
<version>0.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

and one static import like this

```
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;
```

adds the static method...

Comment: what is jsonPath? my code will not build! It does not know what jsonpath is

Comment: @user2428795 what do you mean "and nothing" ? You will either get an import error as jsonpath is not availbale. Or it wil compile and run perform the assert

Comment: jsonpath its  not availbale

Comment: you have not added the dependency then, or imported correctly

Comment: you haven't otherwise you wouldn't get "its not available"

Comment: the issue was I did not add import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*; but I am still getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: json can not be null or empty

Comment: @user2428795 post the error stack trace, although I have a feeling your controller is not returning any json. And you have set the accept header to html... it shoul dbe json